# How to open project from source code in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I am using .net 2.0 version. I am beginner and have started learning .net framework. I have sound experience in php development, so i know in outs of web development.
The reason I am using version 2.0 is because my current company website is in 2.0 and they are not ready to shift to 4.5

My senior has given me project files but now i don't know how to add that project in microsoft visual studio 2005.  Below is screen shot of files i have :
[image]

I need to know how can i add this in MVS 2005.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Oops! that's very bad for u. You should open vs >> open >> click on root of this folder and then add.....create solutions file and then afterwards you can click on solution files to open this

Comment: open -> website - > click on root of folder works for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio : open -> website - > click on root of folder works for me. Thanks :)

Comment: She will be able to answer after 1 or 2 days

Answer (score 0):

You need the solution files to open it in Visual studio. From the screen shot that you have shared, it looks like someone gave you deployed file. When you publish from visual studio you get the files seen in your screen shot.

So ask your senior to give you the "actual" source code.

Comment: Thanks but open -> website - > click on root of folder works for me. Thanks :)